# Which Unicode versions are supported in which OS X and iOS versions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, unicode

Is there a list or chart somewhere that shows which version of Unicode is supported on the various OS X and iOS releases? I can't find any documentation from Apple on this.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for emojis supported by each OS X version. Here are my findings:

- Mac OS X 10.5.8 and newer supports Unicode 4.1
- OS X 10.7.5 and newer supports Unicode 6.1
- OS X 10.11.5 and newer supports Unicode 8.0

Comment: Mac OS X 10.15.1 / iOS 13.2 added support for Unicode 12 - https://www.macrumors.com/2019/10/29/apple-releases-macos-catalina-10-15-1/

Answer (score 2):

Apple is admittedly vague on their Unicode support, but Mac OS X and iOS nominally support Unicode 4.0. See the [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring) documentation.

There are some caveats to be aware of:

Due to the vast number of characters represented by Unicode (in all its versions), you may need to test to determine if a specific transformation or operation is available for a particular character. However, any character representable by a UTF-16 code point or surrogate pair can be represented by `NSString` and `CFString` directly (though their semantic meaning might not be available in older OS versions, and they may render as unrecognized characters there.)

Comment: I'm more interested in the OS than NSString. If you look at the Character Viewer in 10.7, you will see the blocks added in Unicode 6.0. In 10.6, you don't see them. Clearly, 10.7 has added support for Unicode 6.0. I'd like to find similar info for other recent versions of OS X and iOS.

Comment: There's no distinction here. NSString/CFString is the API for accessing Unicode data on Mac OS X, so its Unicode support determines the OS' Unicode support.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is a Unicode Character implemented in the present iOS?

*Admittedly a generalized version of StackOverflow question [41318999](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41318999/218152)*.

```
/// Tests against the existence of a given unicode glyph on the present OS
///
/// - Returns: true if this unicode glyph exists (i.e, not a [?])
func unicodeAvailable() -> Bool {
    let refUnicodeSize: CGFloat = 8
    if let refUnicodePng = Character("\u{1fff}").png(ofSize: refUnicodeSize),
        let myPng = self.png(ofSize: refUnicodeSize) {
        return refUnicodePng != myPng
    }
    return false
}
```

#### Usage

```
let code:Character = "\u{2764}" // ❤
print(code.unicodeAvailable())
```

> true

Requires a method to create a *png* representation of a given character.

A complete description is given on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41393387/218152), with an open source [GitHub project](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-41318999).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that characters introduced in Unicode version 6 (2010) may not be compatible with Mojave or previous releases. I am running latest Mojave and can't render U+2099 : https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2099