# iOS 10.0 + - What version unicode does it support?

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, emoji

I'm having trouble finding documentation on what unicode version is supported on iOS starting iOS 10 +.

I've found that Android supports minimum Unicode version 6.3. I need the same minimum requirement for iOS.

I've looked at the following stackoverflow posts and have yet to find the answer:

[Does IOS support all Unicode emojies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140770/does-ios-support-all-unicode-emojies)

[Which Unicode versions are supported in which OS X and iOS versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352753/which-unicode-versions-are-supported-in-which-os-x-and-ios-versions)

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The current Unicode version is 12. The Unicode Consortium documents all of the versioning (http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/). The Swift language is fully Unicode compliant. I'd suggest checking through Unicode's version history and testing on iOS 10 devices the specific Unicode updates included in version 6.3. My guess is that you will find full support.

Comment: If [pointum answer regarding OS X 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38442010/1033581) is correct, then we can be sure that iOS 10 is at least supporting Unicode 8.0.

Comment: Regarding Android support, you should specify the Android version, because Unicode support in Android Cupcake and Android Pie is very likely different.